# My phone storage is empty when connected to pc

Tags: adb, internal-storage, usb-drivers, mtp

I need to back up all data and media on my phone but every time i connect it to pc everything is fine and my pc recongize the phone but not every time i need to plug and unplug phone several times to make pc recognize it .what ever when i open my phone storage it say folder is empty iam sure that using MTP not PTP my phone storage working on all computers except mine and all phones storages appear on my pc except my phone i have checked drivers and all working properaly .
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

[SD card not showing files when connected to pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134230/sd-card-not-showing-files-when-connected-to-pc) the first answer fixed my problem, just clear media storage and external storage, and boom, it shows all files in internal storage.

Comment: Well spotted. In future, if you think the question has already been answered, flag it as a duplicate. It makes the original question and answer easier to find (e.g. in search results).