# SD card not showing files when connected to pc

Tags: usb-connection-mode, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola

When my phone MOTOROLA G3(2015) is updated to Marshmallow, its not showing files when connected to PC. While connecting, it shows options as charing only, PTP, MTP, MIDI. When I select MTP, it shows the external card, but not showing the contents, where as internal memory is detected and all files are shown.

Answer (score 29):

This is a well discussed and easy to fix bug... Disconnect USB cable, go to Settings, Apps, and Show System Apps and find External Storage and Media Storage and clear data and cache on each one and reboot, then give it 5 min after full boot up to rebuild media databases and connect to USB and select MTP. Should be good to go.

EDIT: In some instances where the SD card contains a large number of (media) files, it can take more than 5 minutes for the databases to rebuild. There is no way to see if the status of this database buildup in the phone itself, so sometimes you just have to be patient.

Also note that some users have stated that this is not sufficient by itself, but sometimes the system cache partition needs to be wiped and rebuilt. Official instructions for performing this operation from Moto are [here](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/105527/p/30,6720,9390/kw/clear%20cache). Note that this operation can take significant time... 5-15 minutes, occasionally even longer, do not interrupt the operation.

Comment: I convert the sd card (16GB) as an internal storage but now when I connect to computer, it only show internal storage (8GB). How can I copy thing to my "sd card" from computer?

Comment: @truongnm This comment is not directly in regards to this question or answer. If you have a different question, please ask it in a separate question including all relevant details. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: I have done all this, still its showing only external card. When connected to ubuntu,  it shows external card and contents. Problem is with windows, i have installed the usb drivers, updated and troubleshooted it. Still nothing happens..

Comment: @SajinShereef If it's working in Ubuntu, you know the phone is working properly... I'm not sure I can help you too much with Windows, but it doesn't require special drivers to use MPT, they are inherent in the OS.

Comment: Ya phone is working properly. The problem is just with the windows I think, anyway thanks for the support

Comment: I had to reboot my phone 2 times after clearing data and cache to fix this issue.

Comment: Some people have noted that after this procedure, access is still not possible until the system cache partition is wiped and rebuilt. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I deleted cache and data for both "External Storage" ("Archivio esterno" in Italian) and "Media Storage" ("Archivio contenuti" in Italian) apps.
Turned off the phone. 
Turned it on again.
Changed from USB recharge mode to MTP, then back to USB recharge mode, then back to MTP.

Still same problem, SD card content is not showing up... :(

UPDATE: after several minutes, content is finally showing up!!!!

Comment: Confirmed to be **working** on LG G3 6.0 containing 32GB SanDisk SD card filled with 17.85 GB of data, and waiting of 20 minutes right after rebooting.

Comment: This worked for me on my OnePlus One - with the MTP protocol. Will it ever be fixed?

Answer (score 7):

After about 4 hours of installing drivers, wiping data & cache of apps, wiping cache partition, etc...

I found the solution was just to change USB option from 'MTP' to `Charging` while USB was connected to the computer, then while still connected, change the USB option back to `MTP` once more, voila!

**Edit:** How to find the USB options may vary between devices. On Samsung Galaxy devices, touch and drag the notification bar down, then tap "Connected as a <whatever-device-type-the-phone-is-currently-connected-as>".

Comment: Where is this setting, pray tell? :-/

Answer (score 0):

After an update from motorola, it works..

Comment: Could you give some more details to help other visitors with the same problem? If you could [edit] your answer to give the build number that works for you, that would let people tell if updating should fix it for them.