# Unable to view SD card files on my computer

Tags: usb, sd-card, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm using a Moto G(2014) model. I recently upgraded my android to 6.0 and I noticed my computer doesnt display my files when I connect via USB. I changed the USB notification option to MTP and now I can view my internal storage files but my SD card is still showing an empty folder. How do I fix this?

**Edit**: I tried to copy files onto my SD card and they transferred without any problem but I can't view the existing files on my SD card.

Comment: I'd your SD card setup as portable storage (external), or adopted storage (internal)?

Comment: I did the adopted storage feature and now I can see the SD card(as internal memory)I was able to see the internal memory even before I did this.

Comment: Have you seen [SD card not showing files when connected to pc](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/134230/16575)?

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have enabled USB debugging and also the usb options that show up on your notification bar asking you to use your device as ptp or mtp.

Comment: What does USB debugging has anything to do with the issue and OP already wrote: "*I changed the USB notification option to MTP*"?