# MTP selected but PC doesn't show contents of external SD card

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, mtp

I have a Motorola G2. I'm unable to to access contents of external SD from PC. I chose  MTP option for USB configuration. I can access the internal storage but not the external storage. The latter is shown as blank, nothing to display in SD card – but it displays the size of SD card.

I already checked solutions available for [SD card not showing files when connected to pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/134230) to no avail.

I also tried to clear the cache of media storage and external storage app from *Settings › Apps.*

Comment: Appears to be the same question: [Unable to view SD card files on my computer](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/137554)

Comment: You still haven't said what your device is, or what type of storage (adopted or portable) ... It would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way (for Lollipop and older versions): power down the Android device, remove the micro-SD, and connect it to the computer via a memory card reader.  Once you're done with whatever you're doing (copying music/photos, for instance), put the card back into the device and power back up.

As noted in comments, however, on Marshmallow, this only works if the storage is being used as "external"; if it's been "adopted" as internal storage, its contents can't be read except by the adopting device.

Comment: This will only work if it is setup as portable storage (external), if the card is setup as adopted storage (internal) it can't be read in a PC or other device, ever.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks, that must be a new ability for Marshmallow; I don't see any way to do that with my Kit-Kat tablet or my Lollipop phone.

Comment: @ZeissIkon it is, Marshmallow can adopt external storage as internal storage,  but part of doing so encrypts it to that specific device

Comment: Good to know.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ZeissIkon "The simple way (for Lollipop and older versions)" – doesn't match the question, as OP explicitly asked for "android 6.0" (also see the tag), which is neither Lollipop nor older ;) Apart from that it of course should still work on MM, as long as the card was not "adopted" as internal storage (see: [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)). Unfortunately, OP didn't leave information on how the card is used.

Comment: What about PTP ? Will the combined memories camera "merged" folder still accessible through a Windows or Linux file explorer ? (When the SD card is in adoptable storage mode)

Comment: @X.LINK Comments are not for extended or off-topic discussion, if you are having issues please research the topic and ask a new question if you have a specific question or issue.

Comment: @acejavelin my SD card is portable means external use only.