# Android 6.0 Marshmallow SD Card Not mounting

Tags: sd-card, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g2

I was having problems with my 32gb sdcard from day 1 . It use to unmount suddenly and I had to re boot to mount it.

Also, the sdcard all folders where not showing when I connected the phone to PC.To fix this problem I followed the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134230/sd-card-not-showing-files-when-connected-to-pc) and cleared data of External Storage App and I can no longer mount the sd card.

Moto g2 no longer detects the sd card. I have tried re booting many times.

**EDIT**

Sdcard getting read in other android phone but not in my moto g2

Answer (score -1):

I had to do factory reset , after this the sdcard was mounted