# Internal storage displays as empty when connected to PC

Tags: internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow, htc

My HTC One M9, when connected as a MTP device to my PC shows the correct portion of free memory to used memory, but when I try to access the files, it says this folder is empty. Any ideas? I am running android 6.0

Comment: Sounds dumb but do you have the MTP drivers installed

Comment: The drivers appear to be installing correctly, it registers as an HTC & MTP device

Comment: Hmm probably a simple fix thats escaping me. i should not be doing this but you can always try XDA fourms

Comment: This topic has been discussed already please refer to this thread: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134230/sd-card-not-showing-files-when-connected-to-pc

Answer (score 0):

[SD card not showing files when connected to pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134230/sd-card-not-showing-files-when-connected-to-pc) the first answer fixed my problem, just clear media storage and external storage, and boom, it shows all files in internal storage.