# Problem with usb connection (MTP)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, usb-connection-mode, mtp

Hi I have very weird problem, when I connect to PC via USB I get two partitions Internal storage (or adopted depending which one is primary) and external storage, when I open external storage there is nothing not even the folders but when open internal storage there is a files from external partition and internal merged there is folder from internal and external memory, also there is folder called 'storage' with sub-folder 'emulated' with sub-folder '0' I don't get it what gone wrong? One more thing when I paste something in internal partition it goes there the same happens with external partition? I tried clearing cache, clearing data and cache for Media storage an External storage, please help!
This marked as duplicate doesn't help me I've have written that I tried that and it didn't help, I've tried everythimg from answers of question but still nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134230/sd-card-not-showing-files-when-connected-to-pc/134235

Comment: @acejavelin It's not I've allready tried that and I wrote it in question, read the question before marking it as duplicate and in my case on one partition is showed all files form internal and external.

Comment: Please update your question with make, model, Android version and if storage is internal or portable (look in Settings - Storage, is the SD card listed under Device Storage or Portable Storage). Note in the other question referenced, there are additional things mentioned besides just clearing Media & External storage.

Comment: @acejavelin you don't understand me, all storages are showed in internal partition (when connected to pc via usb) both device + portable or adopted + portable.

Comment: And without knowing more, there isn't much anyone can do to help you. Your statements are confusing and conflicting, you cannot have adopted and portable storage. I requested information that is critical to assisting you and to determine if more information is needed, but you are not providing it.