# Can't access storage and sd card of Moto G4 when connected with USB to computer and in MTP mode

Tags: sd-card, usb-connection-mode, mtp, motorola-moto-g-4g

I have a Motorola Moto G4, marshmallow 6.0.1. When I connect it to my computer via a USB cable, it charges, and the computer detects the device, but I cannot see the contents of it, namely of the sd card inside. I also changed the USB mode to File transfer (MTP).

I have contacted Motorola already and I tried everything they told me to do (USB debugging option, etc.), but to no avail. They said that there might be a problem with the computer, but I've used this computer already for this operation (but on other phones) before.

I have confirmed that it works on other computers, so I am also pushed to believe that it is the computer's fault. I also installed every driver from Motorola's website.

I deleted the cache already and performed every suggestion in a similar thread, still not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try uninstalling the drivers then reinstall them again. Try the drivers from this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/motorola-usb-drivers-rsd-lite-firmware-t3042687

Comment: A Moto G, yeah. "This is a well discussed and easy to fix bug", see [SD card not showing files when connected to pc](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/134230/16575).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SD card not showing files when connected to pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134230/sd-card-not-showing-files-when-connected-to-pc)

Answer (score 0):

You might be on an outdated version of ANDROID> 6.0/ 6.1
If so, UPDATE your android and the problem should be fixed.